# WinForm DataGridView Multi-Line

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This is my DataGridView.

[image]

I'd like to make multiple lines.

```
From: 1abcdefghijklmno

To:   1abcdefghijklmno
      pqrstuvwxyzabcde
      fghijklmnopqrstu
      vwxyz
```

What do I have to do ?

My codes:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myArray1 = new string[] { "1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "2abc" };
        var myArray2 = new string[] { "3abc", "4abc" };
        var myArray = new string[][] { myArray1, myArray2 };

        foreach( var x in myArray )
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x);
    }
```

and another code page..
DataGridView part

```
        // dataGridView1
        dataGridViewCellStyle3.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle3;
        dataGridViewCellStyle4.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        this.dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle4;
        this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

I think I did all I can do.

Columns parts 1

```
        // Column1

        dataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        this.Column1.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
```

Columns parts 2

```
        // Column2

        dataGridViewCellStyle2.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        this.Column2.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle2;
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines should do the trick:

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

But be aware, the the grid breaks new words to new lines and not single words. So if you write `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` you'll not get a wrap. But if you write `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` you get a wrap.

Comment: "But be aware, the the grid breaks new words to new lines and not single words. " <-- This is the answer. THANKS..